# How to use /testfor for the specific player in a radius for MC:PE 1.1.0.5

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image]

Please help me with this. `/testfor @a[name=<Name>,r=<Radius>]` is not working anymore. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see that is wrong is that what you actually need is

```
/testfor @p[name=yournamehere,r=RADIUS]
```

It needs to be `@p` from my experience.

Edit

It is caps sensitive as well so make sure no caps in your name are messed up.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is a bug, however you can use this syntax: /testfor @a[x,y,z,radius around that position]
For example, to testfor a player within 5 blocks of a command block, you can use /testfor @a[~,~,~,5] (in the command block).
I don't think that name can be factored in though, so the best thing to do would be to report this bug and wait.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do

```
/testfor @a[name=yourname],r=!5]
```

Idk why the !, but it works for me.